# STOMP RabbitMQ redeliver message the subscriber if not acknowledged

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq, stomp

The client uses STOMP version 1.2 over RabbitMQ version 3.9.3.
The client is used for a chat app as a subscriber for incoming messages.

```
a["CONNECTED\nserver:RabbitMQ/3.9.3\nsession:session-paGrRWWiEsYECaWdVdqkXQ\nheart-beat:4000,4000\nversion:1.2\nuser-name:6208370595c29c4357f9b81c\n\n\u0000"]
```

The `ack` header on subscription is `client-individual`.
The client is able to `acknowledge` a message without any exceptions from RabbitMQ.

The problem is, when the client doesn't `acknowledge`, the message isn't redelivered to the client.
I want to have the message redelivered to the subscriber if the subscriber didn't `acknowledged` the message.

Is it possible to create such a feature using STOMP and RabbitMQ built-in solutions, without doing any custom acknowledges?

The alternative worse solution I tried was that I set up `consumer_timeout to 10000` in `rabbitmq.conf`, which should disconnect a subscriber which doesn't ack a message for 10s, then the client would reconnect to the client and fetch the missed messaged.
The problem with this solution is that it takes 1 minute, not 10 seconds to disconnect a subscriber after not sending ack.

Answer (score 0):

How nack messages are handled is decided by the message broker, in your case RabbitMq. They can either be dropped, sent to a dead letter queue or re-enqueued.
The docs will help you out: https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html

In order to use requeuing mechanism you have to use `basic.reject` or `basic.nack` in case of bulk.
How you set it depends on the client library api you use.

Also refer to: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-nacks-requeue

> Sometimes a consumer cannot process a delivery immediately but other
> instances might be able to. In this case it may be desired to requeue
> it and let another consumer receive and handle it. basic.reject and
> basic.nack are two protocol methods that are used for that.
>
> The methods are generally used to negatively acknowledge a delivery.
> Such deliveries can be discarded by the broker or requeued. This
> behaviour is controlled by the requeue field. **When the field is set to
> true, the broker will requeue the delivery** (or multiple deliveries, as
> will be explained shortly) with the specified delivery tag.

Comment: This answer explains how the messages could be redelivered in case when client doesn't want to process the delivered message. It is not the answer to my question.
My question is about how make the server redeliver the message without any answer from the client, in case if client doesn't send any ack or nack, when the message isn't received by the client.

Comment: @Rafal You could test it but afaik, the message will remain on the queue until you ACK it, so it seems to make sense you don't have to redeliver it.

Answer (score 0):

Well...there's lots to discuss about which configuration to choose when using `rabbitmq`. I will recommend the following setup (to begin with)

Use `fanout` model (as described in the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html)). This will allow you to:

- Define an exchange (for instance: for all broadcast or public messages)
- Define a queue per service (thus allowing you solution to scale without having a duplication for the same service running simultaneity on several instances)
- Set manual acknowledge (seems more suitable for your use case) or negative acknowledgement (e.g. - when something wrong happen - return message back to broker). This topic is covered [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

**In short:** yes, there is a configuration which suits your needs
**In depth:** you should carefully craft your setup to suit all your needs (including high availability) in order to ensure that your code and deployment will hold as your project progress

Comment: It's not the answer to the question, I have setup the things you mentioned. The problem is that there are unacked messages waiting in a queue, but I want them to be redelivered to the current subscribers which isn't happening in my current configuration.

Comment: That's legit! If the question is about code - please send some code in the question. I'll be more than happy to review it and further assist

Comment: It's a question about rabbit configuration. I added another paragraph to the question with an alternative solution which could work, you can take a look.

Comment: Sorry, but for me, configuration only without code is not enough. You can have a great set of configuration with invalid code and receive errors / unexpected behaviors (and vice versa). This community is code oriented - maybe you should use https://serverfault.com/ instead